# Some issues with PHP email script

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some problems with a script, basically what I want the script to do is get the form data and post to the database (its doing this fine) then I want it to send a thank you email, this is the bit that isn't working, its just not coming through. Also from what I can tell, the script will send the email even if it fails to execute the script, how do I get around this.

I am fairly new to PHP and just discovering what it can do so I really appreciate your help.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


require_once('Connections/connection.php');
mysql_select_db($database_connection);

$query = "INSERT INTO mailing_list ( name, email)
        VALUES ( '$name', '$email');";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

 $email_from = 'mailinglist@myemail.com';
    $email_subject = "Welcome to our mailinglist";
    $email_body = "
$name,

Welcome to our mailing list, we will now keep you updated on whats going on here.

To unsubscribe go to.".


  $to = "$email";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.php');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure its not going to the spam folder?

Comment: really should avoid using mysql_* functions as they are depreciated now.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Where are you setting `$visitor_email`?

Comment: You really need to read some tutorials on inserting stuff, you need to execute the query but also check the result of the query - i.e. did it work... and only if it worked you will sent the mail.

Comment: @Iznogood Yep, I have checked the spam folder and its definitely not coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code reworked using PDO. I also removed the reply-to value, since I don't know that you can use the users email as the reply-to, email clients may block it.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//I recommend rewriting this to NOT use mysql_* functions and instead use PDO
//The documentation is located at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
/*
require_once('Connections/connection.php');
mysql_select_db($database_connection);
*/
$host = 'host_name';
$dbname = 'database_name';
$user = 'user_name';
$pass = 'user_pass';
try
{
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

$query = "INSERT INTO mailing_list ( name, email) VALUES ( '?', '?');";

$sth = $DB->prepare($query);

//This way only a success will send an email
if($sth->execute(array($name, $email)))
{
    if(IsInjected($email))
    {
        echo "Bad email value!";
        exit;
    }

    $email_from = 'mailinglist@myemail.com';
    $email_subject = "Welcome to our mailinglist";
    $email_body = "
    $name,

    Welcome to our mailing list, we will now keep you updated on whats going on here.

    To unsubscribe go to.".


    $to = $email;
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    //I don't know that you can use the to email as the reply-to,
    //most emails will probably block that.
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //done. redirect to thank-you page.
    header('Location: thank-you.php');
}else{
    echo "Failed to insert into database.";
    exit;
}



// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
// Stole this from w3schools, because it is well done. link is at the bottom
    function spamcheck($field)
    {
        //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
        $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        //filter_var() validates the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
        if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Got the email cleaning function from W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_secure_mail.asp

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time with that, the email still doesn't seem to be coming through though...

Comment: Try commenting out the header() call, and instead echo out the values that are being passed into the mail() call. This may help you determine if bad values are being sent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I had missed the quotation marks around  $to = $email; - I can be such a noob at times! :-)

Comment: Happens to everyone, being a noob is just part of life sometimes. :)